# Rails route for button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm a rails newbie and a question on routes is confusing me.

On one of my pages, I have a form.  In that form I allow the user to fill in some needed information and press a "submit" button.

I get:

```
No route matches {:action=>"inventory_test", :controller=>"test_types"}
```

I do have an action in the test_type controller for "inventory_test".

My confusion is that routes seem to be defined according to the REST model, such as /Users/edit/1.  That's fine, but how does one create routes for things like buttons?

I may be naive, but it seems like if I tried to setup a route in the form:

```
match 'some/url' => 'controller#action'
```

then I'm essentially defining the action for the entire page.  How do I define actions for elements on the page?

When this button is clicked, I want the action in the controller called.  I'm looking for:

```
match "submit_button" => 'test_types#inventory_test'
```

I realize I'm likely misunderstanding the paradigm, so any education is greatly appreciated.

---

Code:
(Note that I haven't tested the form code yet, but hopefully you get the idea)

```
index.html.haml

%div

  %table
    %caption 
      Inventory Tests
      %form
        Inventory Run: %input {:type => 'text', :name=>'inventory_run'}
        Inventory Class: %input {:type => 'text', :name=>'inventory_class'}
        =button_to "Run Inventory Test", :action => 'inventory_test';
```

Comment: You need to look into AJAX, I think.

Comment: What do you mean, "defining an action for the entire page"? Routes are just URLs, they can be targeted by forms, clicks, links, anything.

Comment: So how would I target a route with a button/form?

Comment: can you post the code , the form part which will make things clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are submitting a normal form then this should help

The route match '/url' => "test_types#inventory_test" should work fine.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => "/url") do |f| %>
  "Put your form code here"
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Revert back if any queries .

**Edited** as per code posted

```
%form{ :action => "inventory_test", :method => "post"}

    %label{:for => "inventory_run"} Inventory Run:
    %input{:type => "text", :name => "inventory_run"}

    %label{:for => "inventory_class"} Inventory Class:
    %input{:type => "text", :name => "inventory_class"}

%input{:type => "submit", :value => "Submit"}
```

Just check, it should work for you but i have not tried with it